# Search String with Arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist, string-comparison

in my android application i have tried to compare string with arraylist check it out my below code

```
ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> withoutcomma = new ArrayList<String>();

        namelist.add("chennai , In");
        namelist.add("mumbai, In");
        namelist.add("Usak,TR");
        namelist.add("Ushuaia,AR");
        namelist.add("San Francisco,US");

        for (int i = 0; i < namelist.size(); i++) {
            String[] value = namelist.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*");
            withoutcomma.add(value[0]);
            withoutcomma.add(value[1]);
        }

        String name = "i want to go chennai to mumbai";
        String[] splitname = name.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < splitname.length; i++) {
            if (withoutcomma.contains(splitname[i])) {
                System.out.println(splitname[i]);
            }
        }
```

it returns correct output

```
chennai 
mumbai
```

but not able to get the value for san fransisco because white space, i am totally struck, even i have used Pattern and matches but not able to handle the white space

Can anybody help ??

Comment: Why don't you just `.split(",");`

Comment: Not possible with this scenario. Because you can not get San Francisco when split the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting by white space, you could look for values of your `withoutcomma` array in the `String name`.

```
for (String str : withoutcomma)
{
    if (name.contains(str))
    {
        System.out.println("Found city: " + str + " at position: " + name.indexOf(str));
    }
}
```

And if the order of the cities matters, you can save the index of the value that was found in `String name` with `int idx = name.indexOf(str)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps

Comment: i am facing one more issue, when i use this code it returns all string which are all match with city ex: my arral list having both san fransico and san then this code return both san and san fransisco, where us i need only san fransisco

Comment: You can use break; and continue; to control the for loop? Like add break; to the if-statement when you want to stop at first match?

Comment: No i think it wont work because what's the solution if my required string is in end of the array, even i am not sure about my first match is the one i want, i need exact match, any idea

Comment: I see now, can you add if-s for checking that the string is exactly the one you want?

Comment: for adding if, i need to split the string right so may i need to face the problem of my question again

Comment: hmm then I have no other solution without knowing very specificly the problem. Maybe start a bounty on this question if you cant get it right with these answers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83869/discussion-between-madhu-and-milez).

Answer (score 2):

**Split the words at  commas as well as at any spaces.** So, when ever you get a multiple word place name, store it in the Array, and then use it to compare. works for me.

Use this :

```
    ArrayList<String> namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> withoutcomma = new ArrayList<String>();

    namelist.add("chennai , In");
    namelist.add("mumbai, In");
    namelist.add("Usak,TR");
    namelist.add("Ushuaia,AR");
    namelist.add("San Francisco,US");

    for (int i = 0; i < namelist.size(); i++) {
        String[] value = namelist.get(i).split("[(\\s*,\\s*)\\s]");
        for(String word : value) {
            withoutcomma.add(word);
        }
    }

    String name = "i want to go San Francisco to mumbai";
    String[] splitname = name.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < splitname.length; i++) {
        if (withoutcomma.contains(splitname[i])) {
            System.out.println(splitname[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No it gives me separated output

Answer (score 1):

you can use trim() to omit space in San Francisco,

change

```
 String[] value = namelist.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

to

```
 String[] value = namelist.get(i).trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```